# return text list of values one line per instance-id with awscli --query

Tags: aws-cli, jmespath

I have instances in AWS that have the same ReservationId (they were launched at the same time and they have AmiLaunchIndex of 0 thru x ). My goal is to produce text output with one line per instance, such as this. I added column headers for clarity.

```
OwnerId      ReservationId InstanceId  PrivateIpAddress AmiLaunchIndex
12345678910  r-poiu4567    i-asdf1234  10.0.0.1         0
12345678910  r-poiu4567    i-qwer4312  10.0.1.1         1
... etc ...
```

In the jmespath gitter channel, the map function was suggested as a way to accomplish this, but I can't figure out how to use the function. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, to do this right I think we'd need https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.site/pull/6

In this particular case you can hack this result by using the owner in Network Interfaces, which is almost certain to be the same in practice:

`Reservations[].Instances[].[NetworkInterfaces[0].OwnerId, InstanceId, KeyName]`

(use an object instead of an array if you want the column headings)

Answer (score 11):

```
--query Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId] --output text
```

Just add the brakets

Comment: This one does not work `aws eks list-clusters --region eu-central-1 --output=text --query "[clusters]"`

Comment: aws ec2 describe-instances --region {{ region }} --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=running --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[].[{ID:InstanceId, Name:Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value,EnvID:Tags[?Key==`EnvID`].Value, EnvLayer:Tags[?Key==`EnvLayer`].Value, Type:InstanceType, AZ:Placement.AvailabilityZone, State:State.Name, IP:PrivateIpAddress | [0] }]' --output text | sed -e 's,ENVID,,g' -e 's,ENVLAYER,,g' -e 's,NAME,,g' | tr 't' 'n' | sed -e '/^$/d' | awk '{ORS=NR%8?", ":"n";print}' > /tmp/output-text.csv....I am using this in ansible playbook which is ran in jenkins and getting output

Comment: in a sigle line as well as having \t, when I run this command on cli directly there is no \t but inside pipeline not able to remove this \t as well as print each instance on new line

Comment: @t7e `aws eks list-clusters --query 'clusters[].[@]' --output text`

Answer (score 6):

you would need to run the following command

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
    --filters "Name=reservation-id,Values=r-poiu4567" 
    --query 'Reservations[*].{owner:OwnerId,ReservationId:ReservationId,instance:Instances[].InstanceId | [0]}' \ 
    --output text
```

You can add the other parameters you want

This will provide the desired output (all elements in one line) without the header as something like

```
i-08eec92943c9cc576 325979260958    r-0b13a131efa6b3af8
i-07a25c4ae7e6abecb 325979260958    r-05a51aefe5b72358d
....
```

Comment: thanks, the zeroth index at the end there only displays the 1st line in my terminal.

Comment: also, there seems to be a period missing `Instances[].InstanceId` because that throws an error.

Comment: I fixed the period missing it should work with any number of instances

Comment: Here's a test case - https://gist.github.com/tightly-clutched/92a8aa5fa00ed6391d2ed74bbe971517 - I only get one line of results when I try your code. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I was missing the `*` in `Reservations[*]`make sure to adjust, I was able to run it successfully and returned all instances

Comment: The "| [0]" saved me to return the unique element from an array of the Tags!!! Thank you!

Comment: @MarcellodeSales can you help me explain `| [0]` did here

Comment: @SumitMurari that only means you want the first element of the array :), where[] is the entire array and [0] is the first element of the array :)

Answer (score 2):

```
ec2 describe-instances --query 
'Reservations[*].
{
   id:ReservationId,
   requester:RequesterId,
   instance:Instances[].InstanceId |[0],
   lifecycle:Instances[].InstanceLifecycle | [0]
}
'
--output text
```

....worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to get my desired result by using the map function of jmespath as follows. Kudos to folks in the jmespath/chat channel on gitter.

`aws ec2 describe-instances --query "map(&[], Reservations[].[OwnerId,ReservationId,Instances[].InstanceId | []])" --output text`

An equivalent alternative expression is:

`aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[].[OwnerId,ReservationId,Instances[].InstanceId | []] | map(&[], @)" --output text`

see [this jmespath issue](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.site/issues/15) and [this one](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.py/issues/92) where this is discussed.